# I am not able to run spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have created spring boot data jpa application using gradle's and my project structure look likes below.

**com.duregesh**

```
 --TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication.java
```

**com.durgesh.controller**

```
 --UserController.java
```

**com.durgesh.model**

```
 --User.java
```

**com.durgesh.repositories**

```
 --UserJpaRepository.java
```

**com.durgesh.services**

```
 --UserServiceImpl.java
```

when i am runing spring boot below exception is firing
Description:

Field userJpaRepository in com.durgesh.services.UserServiceImpl required a bean named 'emf' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'emf' in your configuration.

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication.class, args);
    }
-------------
public interface UserJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
-------------
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")   
public class User implements Serializable{
        @Id
        private Long id;
        @Column(unique = true)
        private String uid;
        private String password;
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getUid() {
            return uid;
        }
        public void setUid(String uid) {
            this.uid = uid;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        }
----------------
@Service
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.construction.de.*", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;
    @Override
    public User add(final User user) {
        return userJpaRepository.save(user);
    }
    @Override
    public User findById(final Long id) {
        final User user = userJpaRepository.findOne(id);
            return user;
    }
}
----
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @RequestMapping(value ="/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User add( @RequestBody final User user){
        return userService.add(user);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value ="/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User findById(@PathVariable("id") final Long id){
        return userService.findById(id);        
    }
}
```

Comment: If  am usring UserJpaRepository.java  directly in UserController.java is working fine

Comment: @SpringBootApplication
public class TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication.class, args);
 }

Comment: how have you configured spring ! .. seems like a problem in bean configuration . you have any bean named 'emf' like may be your EntityManagerFactory.. how have you wired that into your dao

Comment: hmm looks like you have mixed up different configuration from different code examples. First issue is that in the your service layer 'UserServiceImpl' you re trying to wire a bean named `emf` which in your spring configuration(not yet posted) i am sure that you havent defined an entity manager with name `emf`. Second issue , is why you want the entityManager to be wired in the service layer ?? Spring Data will take care of your repositories , so you simply have to autowire the repository class as you did in the first place

Comment: Just remove `@EnableJpaRepositories` spring boot does that automatically . You now have configured it yourself and you have configured it with the wrong name of the entitymanagerfactory. But the whole annotation isn't needed when using Spring Boot.

Comment: now springbooting up immediately closing

Comment: see the below log:-- [           main] c.c.d.d.TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication : Started TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication in 3.933 seconds (JVM running for 4.313)

Comment: 2016-11-24 11:57:11.526  INFO 6416 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@479d31f3: startup date [Thu Nov 24 11:57:08 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-24 11:57:11.527  INFO 6416 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-11-24 11:57:11.528  INFO 6416 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Comment: Don't add code/stracktraces etc. as comments as that isn't really readable. Edit and improve your question instead.

Comment: Same code working fine in maven project,but not working gradle project

Comment: Deinum,when i am running application spring service is up after few second closing with below this message"Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' "

Comment: Resolved. Gradle dependency issue

Comment: Thanks guys for quick support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your database `entityManager` configuration for which, you need to follow the below steps:

(1) Provide `@EnableJpaRepositories` to the Application class as shown below (remove it from service).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.duregesh.*")
public class TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication.class, args);
}
```

(2) Provide your database driver and connection properties configured in the `application.properties` (under `src/main/resources` in eclipse or `WEB-INF/classes` folder in server) as shown below:

```
spring.datasource.url: YOUR_DB_URL
spring.datasource.driverClassName: YOUR_DB_DRIVER_CLASS
spring.datasource.username: YOUR_DB_USER
spring.datasource.password: YOUR_DB_PWD
```

Comment: still facing same problem

Comment: You need to do like this::: @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.duregesh.*")

Comment: after annotating @EnaleJpaRepositories on TestSpringBootDataJpaApplication  also not resolved

Comment: Thanks guy for quick response